# Delphi 12 Athens Child Form Flickering

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-12-athens

After updating to the new version of Delphi in RAD Studio 12 Athens, child VCL Forms are flickering in the Form activation event.

Does any one knows the reason?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Q to me. Maybe you intended to post a self-answered Q&A?

Comment: This definitely looks like question with answer. You should post the answer separately. Also it would be good to elaborate the question part more so that people can more easily recognize the problem. For instance is this VCL, or FMX issue, under what conditions issue occurs and similar.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put this code after `Application.Initialize`:

```pascal
TStyleManager.ChangeChildFormSystemBorder:=False;
```

Embarcadero describes this new option:

> Child forms can now have a new modern flat border (the new property is TStyleManager.ChangeChildFormSystemBorder)

Comment: Note that `TStyleManager.ChangeChildFormSystemBorder` only works on Windows 10+, and only applies to MDI child forms, not to non-MDI child forms that have their `Parent` assigned.